# What is the contribution of conductive heating to atmospheric warming?

Tags: atmospheric-science

I know someone who disputes the idea that the Earth's atmospheric temperature would average -18 deg C in the absence of greenhouse gasses. He maintains that conductive heating would warm the air and convective transport mix it, and, since the gasses are not greenhouse gasses they would not lose the heat by radiating it away, and so the heat could build up.

The thought experiment runs thus: a planet in earth's orbit without water and an atomosphere of, say, oxygen and nitrogen.

It seems to me that being such a small percentage (15%) of the incident radiation striking the Earth (even if, in the absence of GHG, the incident radiation would be higher) the effect could not possibly build up because the conduction would work the other way at night and most of it would, in turn be radiated away into space.

In short, he is saying that a significant portion of the effective warming we see in the atmosphere is attributable to this effect, making the basis for calculating the greenhouse gas effect suspect.

I don't have the mathematics to estimate this effect on balance, and it seems to me that it must have been accounted for previously, but I do not know. I would particularly appreciate a reference to a paper or article that discusses this aspect of atmospheric warming.

Comment: The  premise is wrong. What the meaning of considering soil to atmosphere heat transfer? Beside accurate modelling heat which dominates the balance is from sun. Greenhouse gas store that. Non greenhouse don't. Far away to modelling climate but the assertion " since the gasses are not greenhouse gasses they would not lose the heat by radiating it away, and so .." does not make any sense.

Comment: @Alchimista,  Are you saying that non-GHGasses DO lose energy by radiant heat? By what mechanism? Over what wavelengths?  And if they emit it, why would they not also absorb and therefore scatter it by the same mechanisms, thus allowing some heat retention in the atmosphere? (The mechanisms by which GHG molecules absorb and re-emit IR are well understood.) Can you provide me with numbers or evidence to show that? I'd greatly appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: @Alchemista, continued. Absent GHGasses solar radiation would heat our hypothetical planet's surface a bit more than Earth's. Most of that heat, it is true, would be re-radiated in longer wavelength IR which would pass through the atmosphere back in to space. A very small portion of the energy would be conducted to the air within a few centimeters of the surface, to be distributed  by convective mixing. The "meaning" of considering this portion is obviously to calculate what accumulative effect such warming (balanced by the cooling of the air by the same means at nighttime) would have.

Comment: I do not mot any number not modelling the physics of the atmosphere. Greenhouse gas are necessary for the atmosphere that we actually have. If you remove them T will be in due time lower. I mostly pointed to the fact that non GH gas radiates heat as everything else. The point is that GH absorb heat and re emit it partially back. Non GH can get heat by contact but they are already doing it.. And surely they radiate to the vacuum of space up where they can.

Comment: You don't need fine details to contrast a wrong assumption.

Comment: @Alchimista - (1 of 3)  I appreciate your answering, but frankly, I am having trouble even understanding quite what your sentences mean. You commented: "What the meaning of considering soil to atmosphere heat transfer? Beside accurate modelling heat which dominates the balance is from sun." Of course the energy input is from the sun. The whole premise of my friend's claim is that in a GHG-free atmosphere direct heating of the air by the sun would not take place, therefore the convective heating from the warmed surface of the planet would be the only effect heating the atmosphere. ... (cont.)

Comment: @Alchimista - (2 of 3) On the other hand, s/he claims that the effect would be significant and accumulative because without GHGs to re-radiate the heat from the atmosphere to space, the heat would be retained. This sounds like a claim that non-GHG do not radiate heat (have no blackbody radiation at all) which strikes me as incredible. To me this claim also defies all logic because cooling affects during the night (when the atmosphere would be warming the planet) would offset any retained heat. ... (cont)...

Comment: @Alchimista - (3 of 3) The whole claim is that the conductive heating of the atmosphere is more significant than current models allow for. I doubt it highly, but have not been able to find a definitive account of the role of the impact of conductive / convective heating of the atmosphere in any account I have read so far. I suspect this is because it is negligible, just as the BB radiation of the non-GHG components of the atmosphere is negligible.

Comment: Everything radiates. Without atmosphere there will even not be discussion.  Yes the quick point ist that everything radiates more or less a black body radiation. GH gases are just a cover. The point is that IR absorption and diffusion keep more heat than without, like the sky is blue for an analogous vis counterpart, though is mere scattering. Changing the composition you could imagine blue light impinging the planet and being absorbed and/or reflected to space. The blue sky is an analogous of a warm sky, if you get the picture. ..

Comment: For the rest, it might be that without gh gases we would have -18 degree. Surely it would be too cold. That is sure.